# Should a "constructor" function return an error or a null value?

Tags: go

Given the a constructor function such as

```
func NewSomething(name, color string) *Something {
    s := Something{name, color}
    return &s
}
```

Should this function include sanity checks, such as `&name == nil`, or `len(name) == 0`? If this function should contain sanity checks, what value should be returned from the constructor? A `nil` value, or an error (`errors.New(...)`)? An example is included below.

```
func NewSomething(name, color string) *Something {
    if &name == nil || len(name) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    if &color== nil || len(color) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    s := Something{name, color}
    return &s
}
```

Comment: Examples in the stdlib: [url.Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse), [`http.NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest), and so on.

Comment: What led to me asking this question was [this example](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals). Instead of returning an error, the example returns a `nil` value, so you can see my confusion. These examples help clarify what a proper function should look like, in this use case, thank you.

Comment: @battery.cord The [section on errors](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors) in the same document says it's good style to return an error instead of nil.  The example you linked  to comes before the section on errors.  Perhaps the author glossed over error handling because the topic is covered later.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Return an `error`. It is not idiomatic to use a distinguished value (such as `nil`) to indicate an error.

```
func NewSomething(name, color string) (*Something, error) {
  if name == "" {
    return nil, errors.New("bad name")
  }

  if color == "" {
    return nil, errors.New("bad color")
  }

  s := Something{name, color}
  return &s, nil
}
```

Aside: The expression `&anyVariable == nil` always evaluates to `false`. Simplify the checks to `len(color) == 0` or `color == ""`.