# Best practice for handling error in struct's `New()`

Tags: go

Given:

```golang
type A struct{}

func New() *A {
  return &A{}
}
```

What is the best practice-based recommendation for handling an error that occurs during construction?

A real world scenario is constructing a `time.Time` for a specific `time.Location` based on some `location string` that may not be valid.

EDIT:

This is more than "should a constructor func return an error". I'd like to discuss alternatives.

For example, if it doesn't return an error, perhaps we don't allow values to be passed into the constructor that could result in an error.

I'd like to consider the merit to different approaches.

EDIT 2:

Possible approaches:

1. return an error in the constructor
2. only return a valid struct and don't allow potentially invalid constructor params
3. return a nil struct instance on error

EDIT 3:

Rating Criteria

1. Lines of calling code
2. Lines of own code
3. Level of ambiguity

Comment: Return `(*A, error)` from the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774615/should-a-constructor-function-return-an-error-or-a-null-value

Comment: @CeriseLimón I edited my question to clarify. I would like to consider the options based on real world experiences. Returning an error is one option, but it may complicate the calling code.

Comment: 2 is unclear - I'm not sure how you would "not allow potentially invalid constructor params". 3 is unidiomatic Go; 1 would be the correct way to indicate an error occurred, and would actually let the caller know what the error was instead of just "something went wrong no object for you".

Comment: @Adrian see my answer below

Comment: I just read the answer and my comment would be the same - it's unclear what 2 (or the related 3 in your answer, not present in your question) means and 3 (in the question - 4 in your answer) is a poor choice for the reasons I gave above.

Comment: "I'd like to discuss alternatives" This isn't the proper forum for discussions like that. Questions with objective answers are more appropriate here.

Comment: The proper approach depends entirely on your use case. There's no general answer possible.

Comment: To be fair, you could rate each option objectively with clearly defined criteria. That's what I tried to do in my answer. Objectively consider the pros and cons and decide on the most ideal option. PS - I understand this isn't a forum, which is why I've tried to structure the conversation as a question with a possible answer.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the votes/comments I'm seeing, I'll answer this myself and close. If anyone would like to refine my answer, please comment.

## 1) Return an error in the constructor

### Pros

- Allows calling code to deal with less logic itself

### Cons

- Disallows calling code to do inline assignment since it returns multiple params.

## 2) Don't allow potentially invalid constructor params

For example, don't accept a string date which needs to be parsed into a `time.Time`. Instead, require an instance of `time.Time` as a param.

### Pros

- Allows calling code to do inline assignments
- Enables sane defaults

### Cons

- Makes the constructor func less convenient compared to a composite literal
- Could require additional separate convenience methods for the struct
- Requires calling code to handle more logic

## 3) Allow potentially invalid constructor params and use sane defaults in their place

"defer the error until a later function is called"

### Pros

- Allows calling code to do inline assignments

### Cons

- Difficult to know if the desired params were accepted

## 4) Return a nil struct instance on error

This is possible, but just not a good idea. Some would say evil even.

### Pros

- Allows inline assignments
- Allows calling code to be simpler/naive

### Cons

- Not typical (ie. idiomatic) of Go code
- Hides the cause
- Allows calling code to be naive

Comment: Your discussion of #1 is the only that I think makes any sense. #2 is just type safety--no constructor needed. #3 is pure evil. #4 is almost always evil. It probably only ever makes sense if a `nil` value makes sense in its own right. But then it becomes #3, so still evil.

Comment: Realistically, I think you have 3 options: 1) Return an error. 2) Refactor so no error is possible. 3) If applicable, defer the error until a later function is called.

Comment: I agree that #4 is least ideal. I'll edit my answer with your clarification on #3.